# Style text color inside a php function

Tags: php, text, colors

I am trying to style the check symbol (&#10003) in my member profile tab on a Buddypress site. The tab is created in my functions.php file in my child theme shown in the code below. I want to make the check symbol green and bold. Because this is in PHP and part of a function I don't know how to accomplish this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','kleo_my_custom_tabs');
function kleo_my_custom_tabs() 
{
    global $bp_tabs;
    $bp_tabs = array();    $bp_tabs['verify'] = array(
            'type' => 'regular',
            'name' => __('Verified &#10003', 'kleo_framework'),
            'group' => 'Verify',
            'class' => 'regulartab'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'Verified <b style=\'color:#009900;\'>&#10003</b>'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked great! I used a slightly lighter color green to make it stand out a bit (#4CFF00). Much obliged.

Comment: @Hugo  You're welcome.  Please choose my answer as the official solution to your question if you like it the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','kleo_my_custom_tabs');
function kleo_my_custom_tabs() 
{
    global $bp_tabs;
    $bp_tabs = array();    $bp_tabs['verify'] = array(
            'type' => 'regular',
            'name' => __('Verified <b style="color:green;">&#10003</b>', 'kleo_framework'),
            'group' => 'Verify',
            'class' => 'regulartab'
    );
}
```